# Is there something syntactically wrong with my php code? On submission the page goes blank

Tags: php, mysql, post

I have checked each part of this block countless times and can't seem to find why my request goes straight to a blank page.

Directly from the database to show spellings are right, where dataID is auto incrementing primary key and checkID and checkAssoc are a unique key together:

```
SELECT  `dataID` ,  `checkID` ,  `checkAssoc` ,  `completed_date` ,  `time_start` ,  `time_end` ,  `esig` ,  `pass_fail` 
FROM  `dTraineeCheckListData` 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['process'])) {

    if(isset($_POST['1startTime']) AND isset($_POST['1endTime']) AND isset($_POST['1signature'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `dTraineeCheckListData` (`checkID`, `checkAssoc`, `completed_date`, `time_start`, `time_end`, `esig`, `pass_fail`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `completed_date`=VALUES(`completed_date`), `time_start`=VALUES(`time_start`), `time_end`=VALUES(`time_end`), `esig`=VALUES(`esig`), `pass_fail`=VALUES(`pass_fail`)";
        $poststmnt = $db_transpo->prepare($sql);
        $poststmnt->bind_param('iiiiiii',$_POST['trainee_id'], 1, NULL, $_POST['1startTime'],$_POST['1endTime'],$_POST['1signature'], NULL);

        if ($poststmnt->execute()) {
            echo '<div class="alertText">Data Update Successful.</div>';
        } else {
            echo '<div class="errorText">Some error occured in posting your data update, make sure all fields were filled out for the section.</div>';
            printf("Error: %s.\n", $poststmnt->error);
        }

        $poststmnt->close();
    }

}
```

Comment: If nothing is being sent through `$_POST` then you'll end up with a blank page. Try having `else` options on the first two `if` conditions that report those `$_POST` variables as being absent.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)`, make sure that `process` field is actually being sent...

Comment: There's no point in guessing. Just configure error reporting and make sure you can see the error messages PHP has to offer.

Comment: Everything looks like it's being sent, array(52) { ["process"]=> string(1) "1" ["trainee_id"]=> string(1) "4" ["dmDate"]=> string(0) "" ["dmStartTime"]=> string(0) "" ["dmEndTime"]=> string(0) "" ["dmCheck"]=> string(7) "dmCheck" ["openCheck1"]=> string(10) "openCheck1" ["1startTime"]=> string(5) "87654" ["1endTime"]=> string(4) "8765" ["1signature"]=> string(4) "Mike"......

Comment: It seems to be breaking out  on the bind_param statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind_param is pass by variable.
I added in the below code and it worked.

```
        $traineeCheckNumber = 1;
        $traineeCheckDate = NULL;
        $traineeCheckPassFail = NULL;
        $poststmnt->bind_param('iiiiiii',$_POST['trainee_id'], $traineeCheckNumber, $traineeCheckDate, $_POST['1startTime'],$_POST['1endTime'],$_POST['1signature'], $traineeCheckPassFail);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line at the top of your script to see errors:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Comment: no, they should be put into php.ini. if there's a fatal parse error, those directives may never get executed.

Comment: True. You can workaround this case by putting ini_set directives in a file (eg. `ini_set.php`) and including them through `.htaccess` with `php_value auto_prepend_file "ini_set.php"`